# iMessage notifications after wake Yosemite

Tags: macos, continuity

Is there a way to not get old iMessages/SMS notifications that I've already dealt with on my iPhone after I wake up my Mac? It is rather annoying, they are not new messages so why are they behaving as such?

Comment: Are you on Yosemite and iOS 8? I don't think they queue for me and when I read a message on one device it disappears (even from the lock screen) from both others as being unread.

Comment: Yep, iOS 8 and Yosemite... iOS 7 doesn't support continuity

Comment: Ok. Do they appear when the Mac is locked, or do they roll in, in rapid succession immediately after logging in?

Comment: Immediately after login - when I open my MacBook.

Comment: (For the record, iOS 7 doesn't support Continuity but that feature is unrelated to this. Messages on Mac and iMessage on devices have had cross-platform read syncing since at least iOS 7, possibly earlier.)

Comment: Sms relay requires continuity...

Comment: Fair enough, but the underlying issue is read syncing, unless this is ONLY occurring with SMS and not iMessage messages.

Comment: Just curious if you still get have the problem if you go to Sys Prefs -> Notifications -> Message -> *(uncheck)* "Show in Notification Center". In this case, I believe your options are quite limited.